# Slight flickering due to jQuery's $(document).ready when manipulating DOM in DocumentCompleted event of WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, dom-manipulation

I'm using WebBrowser c# to scrape a website and manipulate it before displaying to user.

Example, I want all the Buttons of the current website to be hidden.

I do so by injecting Javascript, but I believe it's too late as the page is already rendered out, thus, a slight flicker (the flicker website has all the button shown) before all buttons are hidden.

(All buttons shown -> JavaScript `.ready(function(){})` inject executed -> All buttons hidden).

```
private void browser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   string js = "$(document).ready(function() { hideButtons(); })";
   script = browser1.Document.createElement("script");
   script.SetAttribute("text", js);
   head.AppendChild(script);
}
```

Code above : JavaScript inject.

How to solve the flicker (when all the buttons are shown for a quick moment before hiding them all back after jQuery execution)?

I have tried manipulating the DOM object in `DocumentCompleted` method by setting its `OuterHtml` to nothing "" or by setting css attribute to `display:none;` but there is still such slight flicker.

```
private void browser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var b = browser1.Document.getElementById("btn1");
     b.OuterHtml = "";
}
```

Is there a way to manipulate DOM objects before rendering out to the users?

What event do I call?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that would work is to intercept the navigating function, pull the page manually and then render the HTML in the browser window.

```
private void browser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
   //Cancel the request
   e.Cancel = true;

   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
       string html = client.DownloadString(e.Url.ToString());

       //Find the text that you want to replace here and replace it

       browser1.DocumentText = html;
   }

}
```

Comment: Good idea! I'm trying it now, however, I'm getting Script Errors when the page loads with the downloaded html string. 
Trying to fix the Script Errors now and see if this works.

Comment: A pop up Script Error when I'm trying to navigate to a website.
Error : Script Error. Url is about:/assets/debootstrapped. Prompting if I want to proceed running script on the page. I think the .js scripts have wrong url.

Comment: Sorry! New to stackoverflow. :) Editted the comment above.

Comment: Possibly, yes - it could be expecting it to be a specific URL but sees that it's manually loaded.  That should be fixable within the JS depending on what line it's having problems at.